# Remove the type of a string so it became a variable of the same name

Tags: python-3.x, string

I have a variable called elias:

```
 nomes = []
 class irmaos:
     def __init__(self,posicao,nome):
         self.posicao = posicao
         self.nome = nome
         nomes.append(nome)

 elias = irmaos('gerente','elias')
```

When I added it to the list `nomes`, it became a string. Now I need to call it from the list `nomes` as a variable, converting its type from string to the variable it used to be.

Is it possible?

I tried to remove the quotation marks with this:

```
for i in nomes :
   i.translate({ord('a'): None})
```

But it doesn't change the type of the string.

Comment: Are you sure `nomes` is a dict?

Comment: ops, sorry,  a list

Comment: It didn't "become" a string, you *added* a string (`nome`) to the list, not the `irmaos` object.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to convert the `"elias"` string to the `elias` object, I suggest restructuring your code such that `nomes` stores actual objects instead of variable names.

How about moving the `nomes.append` outside of `__init__`?

```
nomes = []

class irmaos:
    def __init__(self, posicao, nome):
        self.posicao = posicao
        self.nome = nome

elias = irmaos('gerente', 'elias')
# create more instances here

nomes.append(elias)
# append other objects here

for obj in nomes:
    print(repr(obj), obj.nome)  # <__main__.irmaos object at 0x107b56eb8> elias
```

In this way, all objects `append`ed to `nomes` will still be the actual objects. And it makes more sense since `nomes` is not part of the class, but you are updating it with instances of the class.

If you really want to update `nomes` as part of `irmaos` instance creation, you can:

- Make `nomes` a class variable of `irmaos`
- Make a classmethod for creating `irmaos` instances

```
    class irmaos:
        nomes = []

        def __init__(self, posicao, nome):
            self.posicao = posicao
            self.nome = nome

        @classmethod
        def from_params(cls, posicao, nome):
            obj = cls(posicao, nome)  # create an instance of irmaos
            irmaos.nomes.append(obj)  # update the nomes list
            return obj   

    elias = irmaos.from_params('gerente', 'elias')
    john  = irmaos.from_params('test', 'john')

    for obj in irmaos.nomes:
        print(repr(obj), obj.nome)

    # <__main__.irmaos object at 0x105c6bf28> elias
    # <__main__.irmaos object at 0x105c6bf60> john
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it didnt work, the list nomes was still recording strings.  But you gave me this idea to create a def outside the classm wich works fine now : 

def novo(x,y) :
    x = irmaos(y,x)
    lista.append(x)


novo('elias','anciao')
novo('sandra','visitante')

Thanks anyway

Comment: The codes I posted does not "record" strings, but objects. Did you try and copy it exactly? The only way the list stores strings is if you incorrectly appended strings.

Answer (score 0):

This answer my question :

```
class irmaos:
     def __init__(self,posicao,nome):
         self.posicao = posicao
         self.nome = nome


def novo(x,y) :
    x = irmaos(y,x)
    lista.append(x)


novo('elias','anciao')
novo('sandra','visitante')
```